# How can I change variable value depending on what the value is?

Tags: javascript, html

I am starting to learn some basic JavaScript stuff and It's been really fun and awesome :)
but I have a question. **How can I change variable value depending on what the value is?** 
Sounds confusing, **I hope it's not**.

```js
// added function cVal because it's the one thats gonna change
// the variable numbers in the 'error' variable.

function cVal(val) {
    error = val; 
}

// Main variables
var error = 0;
var span_open = "<span class='error-output'>";
var span_close = "</span>";
var span_open_r = "<span class='error-output warning'>";

// Error message variables
var err1 = "Unauthorized access to directory.";
var err2 = "Malformed server configuration.";
var err3 = "Unauthorized access to file.";
var err4 = "Malformed server database configuration.";
var err5 = "Unknown file type .xyz";
var err6 = "Unknown file type .xy";
var err7 = "Unknown file type .x";
var err8 = "Unknown file type .ztrs";
var err10 = "Cannot connect to MySQL database.";
var err11 = "Error connecting to MySQL database.";
var err12 = "Connection timeout on 'Connecting to MySQL Database'";

// File type variables

if (error == 0) {
    document.write(span_open, "No error detected.", span_close);
} else if (error == 1) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err1, span_close);
} else if (error == 2) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err2, span_close);
} else if (error == 3) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err3, span_close);
} else if (error == 4) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err4, span_close);
} else if (error == 5) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err5, span_close);
} else if (error == 6) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err6, span_close);
} else if (error == 7) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err7, span_close);
} else if (error == 8) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err8, span_close);
} else if (error == 9) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err9, span_close);
} else if (error == 10) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err10, span_close);
} else if (error == 11) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err11, span_close);
} else if (error == 12) {
    document.write(span_open, "Error: ", err12, span_close);
} else {
    document.write(span_open_r, "Error code ", error, " does not exist.", span_close);
}
```

```css
span.error-output {
    background-color:#44d52b;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:18px;
    box-sizing:padding-box;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin:15px;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:7px 7px 15px #d7d7d7;
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:all .4s ease;
    position:absolute;
}

span.error-output:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    box-shadow:9px 9px 20px #d7d7d7;
}

span.warning {
    background-color:#d20000;
}

.cVal_container {
    background-color:#e1e2e3;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:18px;
    box-sizing:padding-box;
    top:64px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin:15px;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:7px 7px 15px #d7d7d7;
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:all .4s ease;
    position:absolute;
}

.cVal_container:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    box-shadow:9px 9px 20px #d7d7d7;
}

button {
    background-color:#aeb0b3;
    margin-top:4px;
    color:#262728;
    width:100%;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:16px;
    border:0px;
    padding:4px;
    box-shadow:7px 7px 15px #d7d7d7;
    border-radius:4px;
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:all .4s ease;
}

button:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    box-shadow:9px 9px 20px #d7d7d7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div class="cVal_container">
    <button onclick="cVal(0)" type="button">Error Code 0 (Default)</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(1)" type="button">Error Code 1</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(2)" type="button">Error Code 2</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(3)" type="button">Error Code 3</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(4)" type="button">Error Code 4</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(5)" type="button">Error Code 5</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(6)" type="button">Error Code 6</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(7)" type="button">Error Code 7</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(8)" type="button">Error Code 8</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(9)" type="button">Error Code 9</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(10)" type="button">Error Code 10</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(11)" type="button">Error Code 11</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(12)" type="button">Error Code 12</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(13)" type="button">Error Code 13</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(14)" type="button">Error Code 14</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(15)" type="button">Error Code 15</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(16)" type="button">Error Code 16</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am hoping so that some of you understand what I want to do here.
So to explain further...
If `onclick="cVal(2)"` is assigned to BUTTON than change the variable `error` to value `2`, **But that doesn't work**.
So what am I doing wrong here?
**Please include javascript-only code, jQuery and others aren't fit for me at the moment.**
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Take a look at the [Switch statement](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) to clean up your code first!

Comment: `Array.prototype.map` even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to JS, hope it'll be great journey :)

Aside clearness of code, changing "error" value actually works in your code. But if you're hoping to get different error after each click, it's not happening, as JS by default is running once, during (or after) page load. So, what you need to do is to wrap some part of code inside function wich will be called after each click (and use something else than document.write).

```js
// added function cVal because it's the one thats gonna change
// the variable numbers in the 'error' variable.

function cVal(val) {
    error = val; 
    updateError()
}

// Main variables
var error = 0;
var span_open = "<span class='error-output'>";
var span_close = "</span>";
var span_open_r = "<span class='error-output warning'>";

// Error message variables
var err1 = "Unauthorized access to directory.";
var err2 = "Malformed server configuration.";
var err3 = "Unauthorized access to file.";
var err4 = "Malformed server database configuration.";
var err5 = "Unknown file type .xyz";
var err6 = "Unknown file type .xy";
var err7 = "Unknown file type .x";
var err8 = "Unknown file type .ztrs";
var err10 = "Cannot connect to MySQL database.";
var err11 = "Error connecting to MySQL database.";
var err12 = "Connection timeout on 'Connecting to MySQL Database'";

var ec = document.getElementById('error_container');
// File type variables
function updateError(){
if (error == 0) {
    ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "No error detected."+ span_close
} else if (error == 1) {
    ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err1, span_close
} else if (error == 2) {
    ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err2, span_close
} else if (error == 3) {
   ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err3, span_close
} else if (error == 4) {
   ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err4, span_close
} else if (error == 5) {
   ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err5, span_close
} else if (error == 6) {
   ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err6, span_close
} else if (error == 7) {
   ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err7, span_close
} else if (error == 8) {
   ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err8, span_close
} else if (error == 9) {
   ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err9, span_close
} else if (error == 10) {
   ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err10, span_close
} else if (error == 11) {
  ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err11, span_close
} else if (error == 12) {
   ec.innerHTML = span_open+ "Error: "+ err12, span_close
} else {
   ec.innerHTML = span_open_r +"Error code "+error+ " does not exist."+span_close
}
}
updateError()
```

```css
span.error-output {
    background-color:#44d52b;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:18px;
    box-sizing:padding-box;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin:15px;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:7px 7px 15px #d7d7d7;
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:all .4s ease;
    position:absolute;
}

span.error-output:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    box-shadow:9px 9px 20px #d7d7d7;
}

span.warning {
    background-color:#d20000;
}

.cVal_container {
    background-color:#e1e2e3;
    color:#000000;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:12px;
    padding:18px;
    box-sizing:padding-box;
    top:64px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin:15px;
    border-radius:4px;
    box-shadow:7px 7px 15px #d7d7d7;
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:all .4s ease;
    position:absolute;
}

.cVal_container:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    box-shadow:9px 9px 20px #d7d7d7;
}

button {
    background-color:#aeb0b3;
    margin-top:4px;
    color:#262728;
    width:100%;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-size:16px;
    border:0px;
    padding:4px;
    box-shadow:7px 7px 15px #d7d7d7;
    border-radius:4px;
    opacity:0.5;
    transition:all .4s ease;
}

button:hover {
    opacity:1.0;
    box-shadow:9px 9px 20px #d7d7d7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="error_container"></div>
<div class="cVal_container">
    <button onclick="cVal(0)" type="button">Error Code 0 (Default)</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(1)" type="button">Error Code 1</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(2)" type="button">Error Code 2</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(3)" type="button">Error Code 3</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(4)" type="button">Error Code 4</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(5)" type="button">Error Code 5</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(6)" type="button">Error Code 6</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(7)" type="button">Error Code 7</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(8)" type="button">Error Code 8</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(9)" type="button">Error Code 9</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(10)" type="button">Error Code 10</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(11)" type="button">Error Code 11</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(12)" type="button">Error Code 12</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(13)" type="button">Error Code 13</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(14)" type="button">Error Code 14</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(15)" type="button">Error Code 15</button>
    <button onclick="cVal(16)" type="button">Error Code 16</button>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This one seems to suit me and it's easier for some reason than the one that Thomas showcased. Thank you Michał :)

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code a bit.
Last known errorCode can be accessed by calling `displayError.lastError`
To update the error message call `displayError(1) // see the errors object for more detail`

**EDIT:** added comments to the .js

```js
/**
 * Error object
 * @type {Object}
 */
var errors = {
  1: "Unauthorized access to directory.",
  2: "Malformed server configuration.",
  3: "Unauthorized access to file.",
  4: "Malformed server database configuration.",
  5: "Unknown file type .xyz",
  6: "Unknown file type .xy",
  7: "Unknown file type .x",
  8: "Unknown file type .ztrs",
  10: "Cannot connect to MySQL database.",
  11: "Error connecting to MySQL database.",
  12: "Connection timeout on 'Connecting to MySQL Database'",
};

/**
 * Display error in DIV with ID 'error-container', based on error code
 * @see errors Defined error codes
 * @param {number|string} errorCode
 */
function displayError(errorCode) {
  var errorContainer = document.getElementById('error-container');
  if (!errorContainer) {
    throw new Error('Unable to display error. Element with id "error-container" does not exist in the DOM.');
  }
  // Reset the class name for the error container
  errorContainer.className = 'error-output';
  // Store the last known error code as a "static property"
  displayError.lastError = errorCode;
  // Check if errorCode is a property in the errors object
  // Also check that we dont try to access inherited props
  if (errorCode in errors && errors.hasOwnProperty(errorCode)) {
    // Set the content of the error container
    errorContainer.innerHTML = 'Error: ' + errors[errorCode];
  } else {
    // Set the content of the error container
    errorContainer.innerHTML = "Error code " + errorCode + " does not exist.";
    // Append the warning class name
    errorContainer.className += ' warning';
  }
}
// Set an initial value of lastError
displayError.lastError = 0;
```

```css
span.error-output {
  background-color: #44d52b;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 18px;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 15px #d7d7d7;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  position: absolute;
}

span.error-output:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  box-shadow: 9px 9px 20px #d7d7d7;
}

span.warning {
  background-color: #d20000;
}

.cVal_container {
  background-color: #e1e2e3;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 18px;
  box-sizing: padding-box;
  top: 64px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 15px #d7d7d7;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  position: absolute;
}

.cVal_container:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  box-shadow: 9px 9px 20px #d7d7d7;
}

button {
  background-color: #aeb0b3;
  margin-top: 4px;
  color: #262728;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 15px #d7d7d7;
  border-radius: 4px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all .4s ease;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 1.0;
  box-shadow: 9px 9px 20px #d7d7d7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <span id="error-container" class="error-output">Press a button to test</span>
  <div class="cVal_container">
    <button onclick="displayError(0)" type="button">Error Code 0 (Default)</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(1)" type="button">Error Code 1</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(2)" type="button">Error Code 2</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(3)" type="button">Error Code 3</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(4)" type="button">Error Code 4</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(5)" type="button">Error Code 5</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(6)" type="button">Error Code 6</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(7)" type="button">Error Code 7</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(8)" type="button">Error Code 8</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(9)" type="button">Error Code 9</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(10)" type="button">Error Code 10</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(11)" type="button">Error Code 11</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(12)" type="button">Error Code 12</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(13)" type="button">Error Code 13</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(14)" type="button">Error Code 14</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(15)" type="button">Error Code 15</button>
    <button onclick="displayError(16)" type="button">Error Code 16</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```